# What is rev-manifest.json file in gulp?

Tags: gulp

I am new to Gulp. Can anyone explain what is `rev-manifest.json` file in gulp?

Answer (score 9):

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: **cache invalidation** and naming things.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

---

Gulp has a plugin [gulp-rev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev) which is used to append the hash of the file content to the end of its name, so for example `script.js` would become something like `script-134cfcc203.js`.

The `rev-manifest.json` is the mapping that stores the original name and the current name of each file.

This is done for cache invalidation. This is how it's done:

You set the TTL (time to live) of your resources (styles, scripts, etc.) to infinite on your server (nginx, apache or whatever), which means that you're telling your clients' browsers that they should cache the resources forever.

Then when you change the content of a file (e.g. `script.js`) because you append its hash to its name, then the name would change. Then when the users' browsers request your page, they see it as a whole new file and therefore they're forced to re-download it. But until you don't change the contents of the file, they never re-download it and hence your page's loading speeds up.

Although note that you also need another plugin [gulp-rev-rewrite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev-rewrite), to search your html files and automatically replace the `script.js` with its new name, and this plugin uses the `rev-manifest.json` file to do that.

Hope it is clear enough. Or if it's not, feel free to ask and I will edit and clarify more

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @getFullStack If it answers your question, please accept it (using the check mark on the left) so that others can easily find and trust the correct answer